# Angularjs Multiselect datepicker array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, datepicker, multi-select

I created a simple multi-select without extending ui-bootstrap by using `ng-change` in conjunction with `ng-repeat` in the tr element. I'm able to select multiple dates and push all of the dates into a table array. But `splice()` that deletes the item and `pop()` that empties the array doesn't work at all.

Here is the link that supports multiselect by extending bootstrap [plnkr.co/iVSdXt](http://plnkr.co/edit/iVSdXt?p=preview)

My controller:

```
angular.module('app', ['gm.datepickerMultiSelect'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function() {
  this.activeDate;
  this.selectedDates = [new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)];
  this.type = 'individual';

  this.identity = angular.identity;

  this.removeFromSelected = function(dt) {
    this.selectedDates.splice(this.selectedDates.indexOf(dt), 1);
  }
});
```

Comment: Seems working well from your code.

Comment: Then show the code that doesn't work.

Comment: I am glad to help, but maybe it is better to ask in another separate question. And make this clearer: `avoid it` means avoid right click or avoid left and right clicks?

Comment: By the way, please kindly upvote/accept my answer if it helps you to solve the problem :)

Comment: just created a working demo with a calendar: http://plnkr.co/edit/sbHcuZRIfrueMOrrJKIA?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check working demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/F9cuInPCBbrR73jUaah6?p=preview)

First of all, [`ng-change` requires `ng-model`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange):

> Note, this directive requires ngModel to be present.

So comes your error:

> Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'ngChange', can't be found!

Add a `ng-model` like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in frompickers" ng-model="selectedDate" 
    ng-change="fromdatepickers(calDate)">
```

Secondly, modify your controller to:

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.frompickers = [];
    $scope.remove = function(index) {
      $scope.frompickers.splice(index, 1);
    }
    $scope.reset = function() {
      while ($scope.frompickers.length > 0) {
        $scope.frompickers.pop();
      }
    };
    $scope.fromdatepickers = function(calDate) {
      var cdate = new Date(calDate);
      $scope.frompickers.push(cdate);
    };
  });
```

In your code, you define `$scope.frompickers = [];` inside the function `$scope.fromdatepickers`, which creates a new array every time. So the array always has one member only.